# Intercepting ASP.NET MVC routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need to transform some url parameters while creating link on server side.

Example:

```
@html.ActionLink("text","index","Home",null,new { id=Model.Id });
```

Now i have to transform id parameter so i can simply convert it and pass it into object objectRoute parameter or i can simply override ActionLink.But  problem is that i have to make refactor on whole project.

So i am looking a way to intercepting mechanism or handler mechanism.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem exactly so I will give you link : [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs). Hope this helps you out

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay - Think that id parameter is 2 and i want to convert 2 to "xxkylmn". I can convert it before passing it but i don't wanna make refactor on whole project. Now it is clear for you ?

Comment: In that case, i think you need to do URL rewriting rather than customizing the ASP.NET route.

Comment: Or in the action do a redirect to the correct action/URL.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish?  Perhaps include the Controller Actions you are attempting to link to and what you mean by "transform" and "convert".

Answer (score 4):

You could try using an ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class ConversionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{    
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var idValue = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
        var convertedIdValue = ConvertId(idValue);

        var newRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.RouteData.Values);
        newRouteValues["id"] = convertedIdValue;

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(newRouteValues);
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to apply the attribute to the action where you want this to happen:

```
[Conversion]
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{
    // Your logic
    return View();
}
```